# Make all spring-boot @ConfigurationProperties fields mandatory on application start without annotating each field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

Is there a way to make all `@ConfigurationProperties` fields mandatory by default, without annotating each field?

Basically I'm looking for the counterpart of `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test", ignoreUnknownFields = false)`.

Like an annotation or property I could set like the `ignoreUnknownFields` but validating my `ConfigurationProperties` class fields instead of the `application.yml`.

I want to be sure that newly added fields won't potentially crash on runtime if they are used by the application but omitted in the `application.yml`.

The example below is how my current setup looks like:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class TestProperties {
    @NotNull
    private Resource resource;
    @NotNull
    private String string;

    public Resource getResource() {
        return this.resource;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return this.string;
    }
}
```

Comment: `@NonNullFields` works at the package level.  If that's too strict for the entire package, then perhaps an `@PostConstruct` method which uses reflection to check all the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wan't done at class level since you can have different types of validation.

But, you can create your own annotation in order to perform any custom validation:

```
 @Target({
     ElementType.TYPE,
     ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE
 })
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Constraint(validatedBy = TestPropertiesValidator.class)
 @Documented
 public @interface ValidTestProperties {
     // you can add a specific message as well 
     // String message () default "";
 }


 public class TestPropertiesValidator implements ConstraintValidator < ValidTestProperties, TestProperties > {
     @Override
     public void initialize(ValidTestProperties constraintAnnotation) {}

     @Override
     public boolean isValid(TestProperties testProperties,
         ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
         if (testProperties.getResource() == null || testProperties.getString() == null) {
             return false;
         }
     }
 }

 @Validated
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
 @ValidTestProperties
 public class TestProperties {

     private Resource resource;

     private String string;

     public Resource getResource() {
         return this.resource;
     }

     public String getString() {
         return this.string;
     }
 }
```